# Preventing Caching with .Net Core API

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, caching

I've written my first API, which is a basic validation API. A client (.NET Core Desktop) application logs in with a username and password. I then check valid licences against a database and return licence details. If the (corporate) user has never used the software on this PC before, some shared initial JSON settings are downloaded.

The thing is, there is a different set of JSON settings downloaded depending on the client's site. When I update these settings in the SQL database, this change does not reflect in the returned data. Something, somewhere is caching.

This morning, I attempted a test:

[image: Picture showing test values]

You can see that I have replaced the JSON settings with letters a-f. When I call the API, I *still* get the full JSON settings field returned, however!

From the Client side, I'm performing the request like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ISetting>> GetSettingsAsync(Guid licenceId)
{
    SettingsRequest request = new() { LicenceId = licenceId };
    IEnumerable<SettingsResponse> settingsResponse = null;

    using (HttpClient client = Client)
    {
        var responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<SettingsRequest>("api/Settings", request).ConfigureAwait(false);
    ...
```

I understand a little about server-side caching and have attempted do disable this with both:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None)]
public class SettingsController : ControllerBase
...
```

at the start of my controllers and in my ConfigureServices method in the API, have called:

```
services.AddMvc(o => 
{ 
o.Filters.Add(new ResponseCacheAttribute { NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None }); 
});
```

But I still end up with the same result.

Another important factor is that if I publish to IISExpress server or Azure, I get the expected results for the first run.

But the second run onwards on IISExpress or Azure App Service after publishing, I receive quite old, cached results.

Something, somewhere is caching my results but I'm at a loss to know what it is. Any help much appreciated.

EDITS based on discussions below:

1. Response headers in Postman contain no-store,no-cache on both the first and subsequent requests. This applies when my API runs on both Azure and IISExpress.
2. I am using EF Core with an Azure SQL Database with the repository pattern. I have tried adding "AsNoTracking()" to my database requests to eliminate the possibility of EF doing the caching.
3. A quick and dirty desktop app put together to query the SQL database directly returns expected data every time.

Comment: Since it's working on IISExpress and not on Azure - the caching is somewhere in Azure. What are you using to expose the API in Azure?

Comment: The API is loaded in to Azure as an App Service. Incidentally, I get the same cached response if I use Postman to formulate my request, so guess that excluded client-side caching.

Comment: I'll edit your Q to add that in :) as it's extremely impor. info; so are you saying it only happens in Azure regardless of if you use Postman or the browser etc.? Everything works as expected in IISExpress?

Comment: Ah - so it's the 2nd run regardless of Azure or IISExpress. Then the caching is in the application - thanks for editing.

Comment: Are there any `Cache-Control` headers returned? If so, what is the value? Any `Expires`? Could you please add the full headers returned for request 1 and 2?

Comment: Apologies and I've edited to show the true situation. IIS Express *or* Azure both provide cached results for the second run onwards. The first run after a publish provides fresh, correct data from the database. The cached data even seems to extend over different sessions after acquiring a new bearer token. I've looked at my Azure configuration but can't find anywhere to turn this caching off. Thanks for spending some time on this...

Comment: Postman shows: no-store,no-cache, also with Pragma no-cache. You may also like to know I don't connect through a proxy server.

Comment: If it also happens on IIS Express, I would completely remove Azure information from the Q as it won't relate and will be more info; a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238453/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-aj).